# Python parse string into Python dictionary of list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

There are two parts to this question:

**I. I'd like to parse Python string into a list of dictionary.**

****Here is the Python String****

```
../Data.py:92 final computing result as shown below:  [historic_list {id: 'A(long) 11A' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.1065599566767107 datelist: 42521}historic_list {id: 'A(short) 11B' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.0038113334533441123 datelist: 42521 }historic_list {id: 'B(long) 11C' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 20.061623176440904 datelist: 42521}time_statistics {job_id: '' portfolio_id: '112341'} UrlPairList {}]
```

****Expected Python Output:****

```
{
  "data" :[
    {
      "id": "A(long) 11A"
      "startdate": "42521"
      "numvaluelist": "0.1065599566767107"
    },
    {
      "id": "A(short) 11B"
      "startdate": "42521"
      "numvaluelist": "0.0038113334533441123"
    },
    {
      "id": "B(long) 11C"
      "startdate": "42521"
      "numvaluelist": "20.061623176440904"
    }
  ]
}
```

**II. I need to further parse key values of id and numvaluelist. I am not sure if there is a better way to do it. Hence, I am converting string to Python Dictionary, loop through that and parse further. Please guide me if I am overthinking the solution.**

**Update: Code**

```
text = "[historic_list {id: 'A(long) 11A' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.1065599566767107 datelist: 42521}historic_list {id: 'A(short) 11B' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.0038113334533441123 datelist: 42521 }historic_list {id: 'B(long) 11C' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 20.061623176440904 datelist: 42521}time_statistics {job_id: '' portfolio_id: '112341'} UrlPairList {}]"
data = text.strip("../Data.py:92 final computing result as shown below:  ")
print data
```

Comment: Do you have an attempt at implementing this that you can show us? Is the format of the input string defined anywhere more explicitly?

Comment: **1.** What you tried to achieve this? **2.** Isn't there any `,` between the `value` and the next `key` in your string? **3.** Is `../Data.py:92 final computing result as shown below:`  also the part of the string?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: All I have tried is to strip the prefix. I don't know how to parse the string values in dictionary key:value format. This is where I can't wrap my head around. 

1. please see updated question
2. No comma. Data as is
3. Yes, but I am able to strip that.

Comment: @glibdud: please see updated question. No, that string value is being sourced from a log file in this format-- [historic_list {id: 'A(long) 11A' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.1065599566767107 datelist: 42521}historic_list {id: 'A(short) 11B' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.0038113334533441123 datelist: 42521 }historic_list {id: 'B(long) 11C' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 20.061623176440904 datelist: 42521}time_statistics {job_id: '' portfolio_id: '112341'} UrlPairList {}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input raw text looks pretty predictable, try this:

```
>>> import re

>>> raw = "[historic_list {id: 'A(long) 11A' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.1065599566767107 datelist: 42521}historic_list {id: 'A(short) 11B' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.0038113334533441123 datelist: 42521 }historic_list {id: 'B(long) 11C' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 20.061623176440904 datelist: 42521}time_statistics {job_id: '' portfolio_id: '112341'} UrlPairList {}]"

>>> line_re = re.compile(r'\{[^\}]+\}')
>>> records = line_re.findall(raw)

>>> record_re = re.compile(
...     r"""
...             id:\s*\'(?P<id>[^']+)\'\s*
...             startdate:\s*(?P<startdate>\d+)\s*
...             numvaluelist:\s*(?P<numvaluelist>[\d\.]+)\s*
...             datelist:\s*(?P<datelist>\d+)\s*
...             """,
...     re.X
...     )

>>> record_parsed = record_re.search(line_re.findall(raw)[0])
>>> record_parsed.groupdict()
{'startdate': '42521', 'numvaluelist': '0.1065599566767107', 'datelist': '42521', 'id': 'A(long) 11A'}

>>> for record in records:
...     record_parsed = record_re.search(record)
...     # Here is where you would do whatever you need with the fields.
```

To parse the subelements of the id, e.g.:

```
>>> record_re2 = re.compile(
...     r"""
...             id:\s*\'
...                     (?P<id_letter>[A-Z]+)
...                     \(
...                             (?P<id_type>[^\)]+)
...                             \)\s*
...                     (?P<id_codenum>\d+)
...                     (?P<id_codeletter>[A-Z]+)
...                     \'\s*
...             startdate:\s*(?P<startdate>\d+)\s*
...             numvaluelist:\s*(?P<numvaluelist>[\d\.]+)\s*
...             datelist:\s*(?P<datelist>\d+)\s*
...             """,
...     re.X
...     )

>>> record2_parsed = record_re2.search(line_re.findall(raw)[0])
>>> record2_parsed.groupdict()
{'startdate': '42521', 'numvaluelist': '0.1065599566767107', 'id_letter': 'A', 'id_codeletter': 'A', 'datelist': '42521', 'id_type': 'long', 'id_codenum': '11'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps so much! I don't understand regex enough and now I understand a little bit better. Really appreciate your time!

Comment: @scott- it only gives me first index. How can I retrieve all?

Comment: Glad to help. If you like the answer and would like to "accept" it, that would be great!

Comment: Just updated the first example, showing how to iterate over the records.

Comment: @MihirPatel if you want help building regexes, this site has helped me a lot: http://regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks @Narek! It's on my list to go over if I ever get through my list.

Comment: @scott- sorry but I am still not able to resolve this. In for loop, the output becomes string back again. I need the data type to be dictionary so I can write the result in csv file. Thanks.

Comment: @Scott The output with a for loop shows different output than original output in your answer. It doesn't stringify values inside the curly brackets- {id: 'A(long) 11A' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.1065599566767107 datelist: 42521}
{id: 'A(short) 11B' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.0038113334533441123 datelist: 42521 }
{id: 'B(long) 11C' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 20.061623176440904 datelist: 42521}
{job_id: '' portfolio_id: '112341'}

Comment: @Scott for record in records:
    record_parsed = record_re.search(record)
    print type(record)

Comment: @Scott Looping through shows record as a single string.

Comment: Yes, record is still one of the raw strings that line_re extracted

.record_parsed is the regex match for record_re parsing of that record.

record_parsed.groupdict() will give you the parsed form I think you're looking for. Note that if you want to break up the id field, use record_re2 instead.